# tensorflow variable constraints

Tags: python, tensorflow

Can anyone help me implement a constraint on a tensorflow variable.

```
def min_max(x):
  return tf.clip_by_value(x, 1.0, 3.0)
```

```
a = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[1.0, 2.0, 10.0]], dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True, constraint=min_max)
```

Now if I print a, this is the output:

```
\<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 3) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[ 1.,  2., 10.]], dtype=float32)\>
```

You can see the the constraint hasn't been applied. Would appreciate any help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable), the `constraint` keyword specifies

> An optional projection function to be applied to the variable **after being updated by an Optimizer**

It means the clipping effect should be applied once the variable `a` is updated by an optimizer. You can verify it using the snippet below.

```
a = tf.Variable(initial_value=[[1.0, 2.0, 10.0]], dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True, constraint=min_max)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    z = tf.square(a-0.01)
grad = tape.gradient(z, a)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0)
opt.apply_gradients([(grad, a)])
a

<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 3) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1., 2., 3.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Without setting the constraint for `a`, you'll get the same values as initial.

Comment: much much appreciated.